# Form validation on click is not working javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i'm validating input fields on keyup and when click on the submit button.

I'm not using input type submit because, i don't want to reload the page after submit the form.

The condition is when input is empty or has wrong value it shows the error message. On keyup it is working fine but on click not triggering

```js
//Validation
function validate(field) {
  var value = field.val();
  var to_label = field.parent().find('label');
  var error = false;
  var error_message = '';

  to_label.find('span').remove();

  if (field.hasClass('validate-field') && value == '') {
    error = true;
    document.getElementById("name").style.borderBottom = "1px solid #ff0000";
    document.getElementById("email").style.borderBottom = "1px solid #ff0000";
  } else if (field.hasClass('valid-name') && valid_name(value) == false) {
    error = true;
    error_message = 'Name must consist characters only';
    document.getElementById("name").style.borderBottom = "1px solid #ff0000";
  } else if (field.hasClass('valid-mail') && valid_email(value) == false) {
    error = true;
    error_message = 'Invalid Email';
    document.getElementById("email").style.borderBottom = "1px solid #ff0000";
  };

  if (error == true) {
    to_label.append('<span>' + error_message + '</span>');
  }
}
$('.validate-field').on('keyup', function() {
  validate($(this));
});
$('#contact-us-form').click(function() {
  var field = $(this).find('.validate-field');
  validate(field);
});

function valid_name(value) {
  var valid = /^([a-zA-Z_\.\-\+])+$/;
  return valid.test(value);
}

function valid_email(value) {
  var valid = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return valid.test(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" class="field validate-field valid-name input-name" name="name" type="text" />
<label class="error-label" for="name"></label>
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" class="field validate-field valid-mail" />
<label class="error-label" for="email"></label>

<a id="contact-us-form" class="btn-submit">Send</a>
```

Can anyone help me here how can get it to be work also on click?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I'm not using input type submit because, i don't want to reload the page after submit the form.` You should always have a submit button. If you don't want to submit the form, hook to the `submit` event of the form and prevent the default action of the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click listener is on a button:

```
$('#contact-us-form').click(function(){
    var field = $('.validate-field'); // <---- HERE is the change.
    validate( field );
});
```

When you do `$(element).find` you aer looking for elements inside the $(element).

Answer (score 0):

@Zain, On Keyup event it works because you are validating only one element at a time, while On Button click, you have more than one field so you have to iterate through a loop as below.
As you get all element with class '.validate-field'

```
 $('#contact-us-form').click(function(){
        var field = $('.validate-field');
    $.each(field,function(index,element){
    // You can add more logic for break look if form is invalid at first element.
        validate( $(element));
    //break;
    }

});
```